# Check session using hooks in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have to check out the session in each controller. If user is logged out then redirect to login page. How could i do it using hooks in codeigniter, so that i don't have to write session condition in each controller. Help me out.

I have following code in `application/hooks/Authenticate.php`

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
}


function loginCheck()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('role_id')=='' && $this->session->userdata('user_id')=='' && $this->session->userdata('client_id')==''){ 
    redirect('login');
    }

}
```

Following code in `application/config/hooks.php`

```
$hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
'class' => 'Authenticate',
'function' => 'loginCheck',
'filename' => 'authenticate.php',
'filepath' => 'hooks/authenticate',
'params' => array()
);
```

When i logout and press browser back button,it again takes me to the login section. It seems that the session is not destroyed properly.

Comment: What code do you currently have?  What have you tried?  What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create AppController extends CI_Controller in application/core/
2. Set in config "my_class_prefix" (?) = 'App'
3. Extends all Application  controllers (closed for public access) from AppController
4. In __construct() of AppController chech session

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, i do not want to do any modifications in the core files. Can't we do it using hooks ?

Comment: "When i logout and press browser back button,it again takes me to the login section."   Press F5?

Comment: The only question at this point is what if we upgrade the framework version ? This customization in the controller inside core folder will work or not ?

Comment: You need copy only controller, model and view folders from old version. Config files in CI 3.0 have changes. Integrate your old config data in new config files.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that by making a function for that...
check if session is not set then and only then redirect on login...otherwise redirect usr on home/dashboard...

```
function check_user_login()
{
    if(! $this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        redirect('login');
    }

    if($this->session->userdata('user_active') == false)
    {
        redirect('your page name');
    }
}
```